# CMake and Config/Modules find_package

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm developing a lib and now trying to make it usable through cmake *find_package* keyword.

Using the config mode works fine. 
I've put the **CPackConfig.cmake** generated by cmake inside the installation folder of my lib by naming it **log++Config.cmake** and it can be found in my project. Fine.
But this method is not satisfying. I need to define my own variables such as lib dependencies needed to link and some custom macros, and didn't found any way to embed this inside the **CPackConfig.cmake**.

So now I'm trying to use the module mode of **find_package**. My concern is that I can't find any way to have cmake use my **Findlog++.cmake** without putting it inside cmake installation folders (which is awfully ugly).
I've found some posts telling to just put this file inside my project root but it's almost as ugly as modifying cmake itself.

Is there a way to have my **Findlog++.cmake** file somewhere inside my lib folder and have cmake finding it without setting the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused between CPack and 'config file packages'. First, understand that they are separate and different. Then read

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html

to learn about usage requirements and inclusion of macros etc.

Comment: Maybe i've missed the point but this does not answer my question. I'm searching for a way to provide my own variables (for example LIBLOGPP_LIBRARIES) and macros to the end user of my lib when it's being configured through a find_package call

Comment: Then add set(LIBLOGPP_LIBRARIES whatever) to log++Config.cmake. But read the links to see why you might not want to do that because you can export IMPORTED targets instead.